# MySQL: Get IDs (explode) from string and use it in NOT IN clause

Tags: mysql

In one table I have such column with data

[image: Source data]

Is there possible way to make a query that return this data in this format:

```
_IDS_
71554
99188
69337
70534
73575
```

as separate ids that then I can use it for example in query

`WHERE table.o_id NOT IN (_IDS_)`

Comment: ```WHERE !FIND_IN_SET(table.o_id, CSV_list)```

Comment: *Is there possible way to make a query that return this data in this format* Yes.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not store values list in CSV format. Normalize it, store one value per row.
2. You may test a value against CSV list with FIND_IN_SET() function. You need the tested value not present in any CSV list, so use NOT EXISTS:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM data_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM CSV_table
                   WHERE FIND_IN_SET(data_table.o_id, CSV_table.WebImages__images) 
                   );
```

3. You may parse CSV to separate values. There is a lot of solutions. For example:

```
SELECT CSV_table.id, jsontable.WebImage_id
FROM CSV_table
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( CONCAT('[', TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM CSV_table.WebImages__images), ']')
                       '$[*]' COLUMNS (WebImage_id INT PATH '$')
                       ) jsontable
```

Comment: NOT EXISTS (NULL) means True in a block of expression?

Comment: @OzanSen NOT EXISTS checks only the rows absence and do not look at the values returned. So you may use not `SELECT NULL ..` but any other value - for example, `SELECT 1 ..`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Akina. SELECT 1 is ok for me. NULL just confused my mind when I think of NULL as being 'unknown'. 

Comment: @OzanSen Null, rather than literal value, is compatible to any datatype.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @Akina fresh info! let me ask you this : NULL falls into any data type category?

Comment: @OzanSen You may think that NULL have no definite datatype. But you can create NULL value of definite datatype with explicit CAST (more precisely you'd set the datatype for a column in the rowset - may be useful in UNION queries).

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
Sélect * from table1 where id not in (sélect cast(strcol as int) from table2);
```

Comment: this doesn not work because CAST change data type but I need to explode ids from string

Answer (score -1):

This should do what your looking for

`SELECT * FROM demotbl2 where id not in (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(',' FROM WebImages__images)) FROM demotbl1);`

GROUP_CONCAT() = combines rows, TRIM to remove first and last `,` which would break the searched array

Hope it helps

Here's a fiddle for proof of concept.. :D ..
[Mysql DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r47LfL9GDnBoULiWf3bgj3/1)

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT will combine all rows into one string literal. NOT IN will act as `<>`. And nothing will be found.

Comment: tested the code Akina . works just fine

Comment: 73575 is present in CSV in 2nd row - but it is returned by your query. Moreover, change the sorting in GROUP_CONCAT to `id DESC` - and all rows will be returned. You miss that you test not `NOT IN ( 1,2,3 )` (integer values list) but `NOT IN ( '1,2,3' )` (one string value).

Comment: Got it. After more testing you were spot on. Good stuff @Akina